# Why can't I cd to my file in cmd?

Tags: windows-command-prompt

I'm typing `cd ~ C:\Desktop\gitPractice`
And I get this return:

```
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

What do I need to fix here in order to be able to change directory?

Answer (score 2):

`cd` expects one argument. You provide two - `~` and `C:\Desktop\gitPractice`.

Furthermore, bash in git for windows [doesn't use drive letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563826/change-drive-in-git-bash-for-windows). Thus the command will be `cd /C/Desktop/gitPractice`

Answer (score 2):

As already said in extension, the Windows "CD" command does not know what a tilde is and only accepts one argument.

- `cmd /?`  help says:

```
Changes the directory or displays its name.

CHDIR [/D] [drive:][path]
CHDIR [..]
CD [/D] [drive:][path]
CD [..]

  ..   Specifies that you want to change to the parent directory.

Enter "CD drive:" to display the current directory on the specified drive.
drive. CD without parameters displays the current drive and directory.
directory is displayed.

Use the /D option to change the current drive in addition to changing the directory.
also change the current drive.

If the command extensions are activated, CHDIR is changed as follows
changed:

The specified directory name is converted so that it matches the name in terms of upper and lower case.
case-sensitive to match the name on the drive. For example
CD C:\TEMP sets the current path to the directory C:\Temp if a directory with this name exists on the drive.
directory with this name exists on the drive.

The CHDIR command does not treat spaces as separators, so that it is
possible to change to a subdirectory whose name contains spaces
without enclosing the name in quotation marks. Example:

    cd \WINNT\Profile\Username\Programs\Startmenu

is the same as:

    cd "\WINNT\Profile\username\Programs\Startmenu"

If the command extensions are deactivated, the quotation marks must be
characters must be specified.
```

Comment: There's some hints it's probably git for windows with bash...

Comment: @vidarlo Even if the OP is running a git/bash or WSL, the answer still applies. The `cd` command under any operating system that I know of takes only a single argument.

Comment: @doneal24 yes, but behavior with regards to drive letters may be different.

Comment: Please show me an operating system that supports another behavior, such as Linux, DOS, or Windows. As already answered, you must do `cd /D N:\other_folder` to change the drive while using the `cd` command to `other_folder`

Comment: @djdomi The `/D` part is what's unlikely to be supported by bash. Bash doesn't have a concept of drive letters like Windows.

Comment: That's right, but on Linux, we don't usually have drives with a letter name. The question was specific enough to be identified as being meant for Windows.

Comment: Yet the error message clearly mentions `bash`, and the path indicates git for windows (which *indeed* has a bash component...). See my updated answer.